# How to highlight and select text in wsl?

Tags: command-line

Recently I installed bash on Ubuntu on Windows. My experience and knowledge of the Linux terminal are very limited and I am not able to figure out how to highlight text to copy the required text or to select the text in the Ubuntu terminal emulator. Trying to highlight the text using mouse has not worked. Please help me.

Comment: What if you select the text and then right click to open the contextual menu ? You can also try to ctrl + shift + c to copy the selected text.

Comment: @ponsfrilus I cant select the text at all.

Comment: You have to activate quick edit mode (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/50050642/960623)

Comment: @ponsfrilus I had already read that article and it's about keys for copying and pasting but there is nothing about selecting or highlighting text.

Comment: Found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38832230/copy-paste-in-bash-on-ubuntu-on-windows

Answer (score 2):

This is a partial answer from this [link](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/copy-and-paste-arrives-for-linuxwsl-consoles/). If you have a shortcut in your desktop, right click on it, click in `properties` and then go to the `options` tab. To activate copy and paste, you need to click copy and paste using `ctrl+shift+C|V`  checkbox. To highlight text, you need to enable(check mark) the `edit mode` checkbox. This was tested in WSL in Windows 10.

Note that this  is only a partial solution as this will not work if you start WSL from Windows Explorer. As described in the link above, it depends where you are calling WSL from. Hopefully somebody else adds to this answer. In the meantime, this solution works for me.

Comment: For me after highlighting text a plain `CTRL`+`C` copies to clipboard. To paste from clipboard a simple right click does that. I do start Bash from a desktop shortcut but haven't check the properties in a long time and am booted in Ubuntu right now and not Windows 10 so can't check.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix you are correct. I am not sure if this is actually enabled when "edit mode" is checked. I confirmed it only works after you start wsl from a shortcut (so after the shortcut properties have been set). So this is how it works: Highlight text then either ctrl+c or ctrl+shift+c. To paste either: right click or ctrl+shift+v  (really too bad ctrl+v does not work). Nevertheless your contribution is very neat. Now having the right click feature narrows the behavior close to Linux as it  uses mouse middle button to paste. It will be great to standardize  this to any wsl console.

Comment: The other consideration is I always install VCXSrv so I can use Ubuntu GUI and it has hooks into Windows clipboard to copy Ubuntu GUI properly. That might also influence CLI terminal but I haven't tested without VCXSrv installed.